# Регулярные выражения в php. Исключения.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Всем привет. Работаю с регулярными выражениями в пхп и не могу доработать регулярное выражение до нужного результата.

```
([a-z0-9]{4,20})
```

Таким методом я отбираю нужные и возможные слова от 4 до 20 символов.
P.S. Реализую возможность идентификации пользователей по никам, как в твиттер. http://site.com/username

Но из-за конфликтов со страницами нужно добавить исключения слов в регулярное выражение.

То есть, регулярное выражение должно быть правдиво для слов от 4 до 20 символов и ложно для (желательно массива) слов или же перечисляя их прямо в выражение.

Как можно доработать выражение? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Делай проверку в два этапа. Первый фильтрует строку по регулярке, а второй - по массиву исключений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/^(?(?!(?:admin|root|passwd)$)[a-z0-9]{4,20})$/';

echo preg_match($pattern, "abba"); // 1
echo preg_match($pattern, "root"); // 0
echo preg_match($pattern, "admin"); // 0
echo preg_match($pattern, "adminko"); // 1
```

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но регулярка не рабочая получилась.
http://www.regexpr.ru/?pattern=%2F%5E%28%3F%28%3F%21%28%3F%3Aadmin%7Croot%7Cpasswd%29%24%29%5Ba-z0-9%5D%7B4%2C20%7D%29%24%2F&subject=nik%0D%0Aprofile%0D%0Amain

На сайте тестирование этой регулярки.

Comment: Регулярка [*работает*](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Aimuol) именно так, как написано в моем ответе. Если вам нужно сопоставлять со списком именно через `preg_match_all()`(как это делается, на приведенном вами сайте), то используйте модификатор [`PCRE_MULTILINE`](http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) и не забудьте, что в этом случае у вас на конце строки будет `\n`.

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался.